# How to call function inside the listener

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Does anyone know how to call the function inside the listener? I did something like this, is it correct?

My function:

```
const toggleShowModal = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  }
```

My listeners:

```
<Tab.Screen
      name='Comments'
      listeners={() => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowModal(true);
        toggleShowModal();
      }
      })}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think what you did is correct, but if you see the code `showModal` will always return `false`. What you did:

`setShowModal(true)` means `showModal = true`
then
`setShowModal(!showModal)` in `toggleShowModal()` means `!showModal = !true = false`